# I can't read a json object with fetch in react from my database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that when I use fetch with the "get" method, and then I try to pass the response from my database in sql to my object with useState, it throws me an empty object, whereas when I print it by console to the Answer from my database throws me a json with all the data.
Attachment screenshots

```js
//Mi hook
 const [items, setItems] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
       //isSuscribed prevents react from failing when the database is //restarting
        let isSuscribed = true
        if (isSuscribed) {
            if (submmit && Object.keys(error).length===0 ) {
                let {email,password} = values;
    //URL  of my local api            
    var Url = `http://localhost:4000/BD/Usuarios/validate/${email}/${password}`;
                //setValues({email:"",password:""});

                fetch(Url)
                    .then(res=>{
                        setLoading(true);
                        /*
                          Some code here 
                        */
                          res.json()
                            }).then(data=>{
                                console.log(data);
     //{name: "name", lastname: "lastname", contraseña: "handleemail", email: "email@hotmail.com"}
                                setLoading(false);
                                setProblem(null);
                                setItems(data);
                                console.log(data.name);
                                //undefined
                                console.log(items);
                                //{name: null, lastname: "", contraseña: "", email: ""} 
                            })
                        .catch((error)=>{
                        console.warn(`New Error ${error}`);
                    });
                            
                    
                    console.log(FakeAuth.tokens);
                    
                    if (FakeAuth.tokens.name) {
                        auth.signin(()=>{
                            history.replace(from);
                        });
                    }
            };
        }
        
        return () => isSuscribed=false
    }, [error]);
```

Now when I refresh again, my page just updates my useState, and items get the values ​​of the data sent by my api

Comment: checkout typeof data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess, and say that it's returning a string, that you will then need to parse using `data=JSON.parse(data)`. The Fetch API will return a string.